# How do I remove "Birthdays" from Google Calendar?

Tags: google-plus, google-calendar

I noticed a turquoise entry had creepily appeared on my Google Calendar for someone called "Gavin" (I know several). A recent update adds a "Birthdays" calendar. It turns out these come from Google+ Circles. Apparently Google+ is still running. I use the calendar in month view, and this is really annoying. How do I remove it?

"Calendar Settings" has the "SHOW IN LIST" tickbox greyed out. The main view only seems to allow me to change its colour. The only option in "Birthday Details" is to change the name to something personally offensive about Google employees. Should I just delete everything from Google+?

Comment: See [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70444/1512) for instructions on how to remove it.

Comment: @Alex Isn't that question a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Since that one has an answer already, I will mark this one as the duplicate, even though yours is slightly older.  It won't make any difference, though, really.  If you think your issue is slightly different, please edit your post to include the differentiating factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the list of "My calendars", where it shows a color sample for each calendar including "Birthdays", click the color sample to hide that calendar:

[image]

BTW the info on birthdays can come from your Contacts as well as Google+.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried clicking there, but that works (now).

Comment: FYI: this is only hiding the events from the main view, but doesn’t delete the calendar.

Comment: To unsubscribe from it, see [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70444/1512).