# Is there a way to remove the "Tasks" calendar in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-tasks

A "Tasks" calendar appears in my list of "My Calendars" in Google Calendar. It's only a minor irritation, but I have a small screen, I don't want it and never plan to use the Task list. Can I stop it appearing or remove it? When I look at the Settings page for my Google Calendar account, it appears that it cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

June 11, 2023 Update: I've reworked my userstyle script to adapt to the changes that Google made to the HTML of the Calendars web app.  While the script doesn't work on my end (I use the extension Stylem, which doesn't seem to support the `:has()` selector yet), I presume that the script would work in a userstyle extension that does support the `:has()` selector.  If your extension complains about the `:has()` in this script, you may have to update your extension (or wait for a newer release of your extension that supports that selector if the most recent release does not yet do so).

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document regexp("https?://.*\.google\.com/calendar.*") {

  div[aria-label="My calendars"] {
    height: unset !important;
  }
  
  div.XXcuqd {
    transform: unset !important;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  div.XXcuqd:has(input[aria-label="Tasks"]:not([checked=""]) ) {
    display: none !important
  }

}
```

Additionally, due to [a privacy issue that Stylish had a while back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish#Privacy_issues), I would recommend using an alternative extension such as Stylus or Stylem over Stylish.

For archival purposes, the original answer is below:

I recently set up the following Stylish script as a very hackish workaround for this:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document url-prefix("https://www.google.com/calendar") {

  .calListChip[title='Tasks'] {
    display: none;
  }

  #calcontent.eui-t .calListRow {
    height: unset;
    line-height: unset;
    max-height: 19px;
  }

  .calListRow {
    height: unset;
  }

}
```

The CSS selects the div containing the content for the Tasks entry and sets it to not display.  It also sets the divs which allocate space for calendar entries to use max-height rather than height to determine their size, which in turn allows these divs to collapse if they contain no rendered content (such as in the case of the Tasks calendar entry).

This CSS will not get rid of the 1 pixel white border at the bottom of the Tasks entry.  If the background of your calendar listing is white, this will be unnoticeable, but if the background of that section is a color other than white, you will have a double thickness border where the Tasks entry used to be.

If you wish to remove the Birthdays calendar as well, add the following code block to the indented section of the Stylish script:

```
  .calListChip[title='Birthdays'] {
    display: none;
  }
```

Comment: Hey, your selector has the issue of hiding more than just the tasks one. Why not use this selector: `.calListChip[title='Tasks']`. This selector is associated with any calendar item that has the title "Tasks". Should hide **only** the Tasks one. Works for me!

Comment: @Fogest While that selector does indeed affect only the Tasks calendar, it selects the div _inside_ the one that allocates space on the page for the calendar entry.  The downside to that method is that it leaves a visually blank space between calendar entries where the "Tasks" entry used to be.  It's not a bad solution, but it has its own negative side effects.  In the most ideal case, you would select the _parent_ of that selector (doing so would do exactly what we want), but at this time, CSS does not yet support that.

Comment: @Fogest After looking at my DOM editor once more in light of your comment, I updated my answer with a Stylish script that uses your suggestion and incorporates additional CSS tweaks that appear to fix the "gap in the entries" issue that your suggestion originally had (though I've only tested it on my own browser).  See if the current answer works better on your end.  Thanks for the suggestion, by the way.

Comment: I installed the [Stylish extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) for Chrome and made a style using the code in this post. My Google Calendar page wouldn't load, so I uninstalled the Stylish extension from Chrome, but my calendar still wouldn't load. My calendar loaded without issues when I used Edge. I uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome, and now my calendar loads just fine. I'm guessing this was an issue with the Stylish extension.

Comment: Similar to Josh, this code no longer seems to work on Google Chrome + Stylish.

Comment: @Josh I posted an update to my answer.  I can't attest to whether it will work on your end due to the updated version's use of recent CSS spec (it doesn't actually work on my side, but I've successfully tested everything except for the unsupported :has() bit), but it's the best that I'm able to do (Google's webpage design has become particularly annoying to write CSS userscripts for).

Comment: @jonathanking Since I can apparently only ping one person per comment, see the above comment.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, [like the "Birthdays" calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/72554/354), you can't unsubscribe or otherwise remove the "Tasks" calendar. The best you can hope to achieve is to not have any entries appear in your calendar (by de-selecting it).

The Tasks widget on the right is at least hide-able/removable. (Click the close button on the widget or minimize the whole panel.)

Comment: At least the birthdays calendar can be made invisible in the settings. The fact that Tasks is missing there led me here ... :( What's likewise annoying: You can change the title of the birthdays calendar - which is handy as this allows to group related calendars like e.g. this: "Family: Deaths", "Family: Birthdays", "Family: Jubilees" - but not so for "Tasks", which is there like some massive blackhole.

Answer (score 2):

If you own all your Calendars, you can drive Tasks and Reminders to the bottom of the list by changing the names all of your calendars to be alphanumerically above R. I use numbers to make them appear in order of importance.

For example

```
Events
01 Routine
02 Paid Work
03 Family
Tasks
Reminders
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out - hit the Cog when viewing your calendar and switch your view (temporarily) from "Compact" to "Cozy". An arrow will appear on the divider between your calendar and task list. Click that! Then you can switch back to "Compact".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove **Tasks**, it has the same active-status as your primary calendar. You can see this under *Settings(Cog Wheel)->Calendar(Tab)->'SHOW IN LIST'*, it is greyed out for **Tasks** just like for your **Primary Calendar** :(.

Why? Heck if I know. Maybe Google is just so large that it got lost in confusion :(. Whatever the reason, just add a Calendar Task for 'Enable Show in List for the Task calendar' to your Google Calendar ;)...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can switch to reminders by selecting the dropdown menu next to the "Tasks" calendar as shown here: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really a fix, but if you hit the dropdown arrow on the left of MY CALENDARS they all disappear. At least you don't have to see it. This works the same for OTHER CALENDARS btw.